# unquoted column names of a data frame in select function

Tags: r

I'm encountering a confusion when doing my homework, the problem is as below:
Does this function defined below work if you provide it unquoted column names of a data frame? In 3-4 sentences, explain why or why not.

```
sel <- function(x, col_names) {
select(x, col_names)}
```

I take iris data as a example:

```
Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width    Species
   5.1              3.5           1.4             0.2        setosa
```

I tried

```
select(iris, Sepal.Length)
```

it worked well,
but when tried

```
sel(iris, Sepal.Length)
```

it didn't work, erro message is as below:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...): can't find 'Sepal.Length'
```

Can anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unquoted column names do not work as it is in a function, one way is to use curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator from `rlang`.

```
library(rlang)
sel <- function(x, col_names) dplyr::select(x, {{col_names}})

sel(iris, Sepal.Length) %>% head

#  Sepal.Length
#1          5.1
#2          4.9
#3          4.7
#4          4.6
#5          5.0
#6          5.4
```

which is a successor to previous `enquo` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
sel <- function(x, col_names)  dplyr::select(x, !!enquo(col_names))
```

Comment: Thanks,I learn the trick.When the function is running, the unquoted column name is involved and treated as illegal because of not being defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either an rlang/tidyeval approach or in this case a base R approach also works with dot, dot, dot.

```
library(dplyr)

sel <- function(x, ...) select(x, ...)

# tests
sel(iris, Sepal.Length)
sel(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
```